# Admob real ads are not showing but test ads are showing

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

I have implemented Admob banner ads inside my other android apps and I know the procedure to implement Admob banner ads. But now when I have a new Playstore account and new Admob account and I tried to implement Admob real live ads are not showing. It is showing blank but test ads are showing properly.

I had tried putting my other app's ad-id and it is showing ads.I have created the ad ids before 6 days and still, no live ads are shown.

Comment: can you please share you code?

Comment: @sameeralakshitha: edit comments are to explain what you changed, not to add question content.

Comment: @halfer ok. I edited in some few spelling an errors only.

Comment: @ApurvaKolapkar as I said it is working for my previous app's ad id there is nothing wrong in the code

Comment: Guys I found the reason why ads were not showing. I have not given my account payment information that was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue before
you need to update android studio
and use latest versions of Google services and AdMob.

Also, try to not change the size of the banner